# Uploadify: Defining maximum image width and height

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, resize

I want to restrict the maximum width and/or height of an uploaded image (jpg, png, gif, bmp, ...). How can this be done with Uploadify?

I can think of two general possibilities:

- check the image size before upload and output an error
- resize image after upload

How have you done this with uploadify?

The only way now I can think of is to extend the code in `uploadify.php` and resize the image afterwards. The problem here is that different images should have different image size limits ...

Comment: I normally check the size of the image after upload and if it is larger than 1200px wide I resize it proportionally to that width. As long as people aren't coming to your site to download high quality photos you shouldn't need anything larger than that. Also depending on the site sometimes I go ahead and create a thumbnail version also.

Comment: This would have to be done server-side as uploadify has no way of determining the height and width of an image from local storage. You could check the height and width when it arrives server-side and either reject it or process it.

Comment: @Pitchinnate: So in my case after `move_uploaded_file`? How do you cope with different image types (png, jpg, ..)? Furthermore I would have to distinguish different images (for different sections)?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: How can I reject in uploadify.php? Perhaps one could write an ajax call in `onUploadSuccess` and delete/crop the image if not suitable or output an error ...

Comment: There are plenty of classes already built that can handle all the different file types for you. One I have used in the past is SimpleImage [http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/]

Comment: I'd have to look at uploadify.php more closely but you could look at the image's dimensions then delete the file after move_uploaded_file if it doesn't meet the requirements. You should be able to provide a response to the user based on that.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by distinguishing different images. Are you talking about thumbnails? Normally I just create another image with `_thumb` appended to the file name for the thumbnails. So depending on where you are displaying the image you can choose to use the thumbnail or normal version.

Comment: @Pitchinnate: I have different images: logos, icons, product images, ... So for each type I would need different max. image height/width.

Comment: You will probably want to pass those variables via javascript to php or you can have different `uploadify.php` files, (i.e. uploadify_logo.pnp, uploadify_icon.php) then you just change that value in your javascript array that calls uploadify.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to do it after upload in your server , there are lot of open libraries for that,  but  @ client side using Uploadify  might not be possible for Height or width  but for file size it is possible

please find @ http://www.uploadify.com/about/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check this option in sizeLimit ....

http://stayinsanvicente.com/homepage/code/customizing-uploadify

```
//'sizeLimit' : 1024*1024, //1 MB limit
//'sizeLimit'   : 800*800,
'sizeLimit'   : 5120*5120,
```