# Uploadify fix selected image size must be exactly 100x100

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I know in uploadify able set the size limit of the file:

example:

```
'fileSizeLimit': '1MB',
```

But how to set selecting image must exactly 100x100 width and height ?

I tried `'fileSizeLimit': '100*100',` but lower than 100*100 also able to select.

Any suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271290/uploadify-defining-maximum-image-width-and-height

Comment: @ZebRawnsley different ... and i have mention i tried `'fileSizeLimit': '100*100'`